# Using PicoSDK in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dll

I try to remotly control my picoscope ps3000a with the PicoSDK from Python. I found the [PicoSDK-Python-Wrapper](https://github.com/picotech/picosdk-python-wrappers%20%22PicoSDK-Python-Wrapper) project on Github. But I can't actually figure out how to embed it in my project. I can run the example but already when I try to load the SDK dll I fail.

I copied the `setup.py` in my project and when I run it I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "picoscope_3000.py", line 16, in <module>
    result = ctypes.WinDLL(find_library('ps3000a'))
  File "C:\Users\ajaeggi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

So what's the difference to running it from the original source, what dependencies did I miss?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for remotely controlling the PicoScope as I hitting problems with it myself.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's best if you create a question and I answer it there

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously much too late for OP but I am answering for future reference:

1. Install the driver by connecting the scope over USB to the PC.
2. Install the DLLs for your device [here](https://www.picotech.com/downloads#t4).
3. Add the installation directory (by default `C:\Program Files\Pico Technology\PicoScope 7 T&M Stable`) to your environment variables (Start > Type "environment variables" > Click "Environment Variables..." > In User variables for $username$, "Path" and "Edit..." > Click "New" > Add the parent path of the DLLs).
4. Restart your computer.
5. Activate your virtual environment.
6. Install the [`picosdk`](https://github.com/picotech/picosdk-python-wrappers) library directly from GitHub by running `pip install git+https://github.com/picotech/picosdk-python-wrappers.git` inside your virtual environment.
7. Import the library by adding `import picosdk` inside your scripts.

Best of luck!

Comment: This stuff should be in programmer's guide or readme. Shame that they didn't include it. Great thanks, now I can work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go inside the setup.py script and remove the try-catch parts, like the following:

```
if not os.path.exists(signalfile):
    name = 'ps2000'
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        result = ctypes.WinDLL(find_library(name))
    else:
        result = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library(name))

    open(signalfile, 'a').close()
```